# What's the meaning of "not so much" in these sentences?

Tags: meaning, comparison

What does **Not so much** mean in the following expressions?

> Pete is tall; his brother not so much.
>
> Pete is very tall; his brother not so much.

Does the first one mean?

> 1. that Pete's brother is short
> 2. that he is average
> 3. that he is not tall

How about the second one?

> 1. that he is not really tall (maybe a little tall)
> 2. that he is not very tall

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is a sassy idiom in the English language that is meant to elicit a giggle. Think of it as a euphemism. The point being made in both cases is that if you had the two people stand next to one another you would laugh and the difference in size. From a factual point of view, all you can know for sure is that Pete is taller to some extent than his brother.

Answer (score 0):

As per the context of a, comparatively his brother is short.
As per the context of b, his brother is shorter than Pete.

Comment: Pete is (a) taller than average, (b) much taller than average. All that we can deduce about his brother is that he is not as tall as Pete.

Comment: with much respect, it would be nice if you mention some sources or cite dictionary definitions. Thanks.